# Get Top N for particular column value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I have collected of statistics, with 3 columns: id, year, and points. I would like to get the top N rows ordered by points per year. In the real scenario, there are more columns, but if I can get the ID and year, and get the rest using a subselect. Is there an easier way to do this rather than doing each year individually?

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER and partition by year.

Comment: Can you toss a quick SQL? I have never used ROW_Number()

Comment: Pradeep already posted one as an answer. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OVER clause` with `window functions` to top N per group results

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY year
                    ORDER BY points Desc) Rn,
                *
         FROM   tablename)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn <= 10
```

Comment: You'll likely want to ORDER BY Points DESC

Comment: Also consider what should happen with ties. That is, what should be the top two of the following set: 1, 2, 2, 17? You could return 1, 2, 2 (in which case you'd probably want to use dense_rank() instead of row_number()) or you could return just one of them (an arbitrary one, but row_number() will work as written). There's no right answer; it's just a choice.

Comment: @BenThul If I use `Dense_Rank` then it is not going to return `Top N` rows in your example it will return `Top N+1` rows.

Comment: That is exactly my point. In my example, there are multiple rows that qualify as being the second highest. If you want to return all of them, you'd use `dense_rank()`. If you just want to return an arbitrary one, use `row_number()`. As I said, it's a choice: there's no right or wrong answer here.